# Cannot access changed root directory for apache localhost

Tags: apache, lampp

I am using Linux mint 15 with lampp apache.

The Apache was working fine.

I changed the root directory from /opt/lampp/htdocs/ to a folder /home/nav/Desktop/PHP.But now  when I access localhost ,I am getting `Access Forbidden Error 403`.How can I solve it?

Error log entry.
`[Sat Jul 27 13:57:04.083556 2013] [core:error] [pid 10332] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:39380] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/naveen/Desktop') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path`.

I have seen many similar questions on the SO but nothing helped me.

Comment: chown -R www-data:www-data your/dir (add your user name to www-data group as well) Also check that Apache is allowed to list directories.

Comment: @JayBhatt :I am new to linux can you please tell the command I should use.

Comment: try this chown -R www-data:www-data /home/nav/Desktop/PHP this should fix your problem. Ignore rest.

Comment: @JayBhatt: The problem is still there.No effect.

Comment: put a blank index.php or index.html file in /home/nav/Desktop/PHP folder and try restarting apache server

Comment: refer this for a detailed solution http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-403-forbidden-error-and-solution/

Comment: Error log says this : `[Sat Jul 27 13:57:04.083556 2013] [core:error] [pid 10332] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:39380] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/naveen/Desktop') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path`.I hope you can help now. I visited the above link but few things I didn't get.

Comment: See the edited question with log error entry.

Comment: Your home directory `/home/nav` is most likely only readable by your user, but it must be _executable_ by the apache user to be used as a htdocs dir. You need to `chmod o+x /home/nav` so that the directory can be traversed (though not read) by apache.

Comment: In the end when you `ls -l /home` you should see `drwx-----x. 29 nav  nav   4096  nav` or something very similar. The important thing is that last `x` which is the execute permission for other users.

Comment: I did `chmod o+x /home/nav` and then `ls -l /home` it shows `total 4
drwxr-x--x 27 naveen root 4096 Jul 27 12:46 naveen`.But the problem is not solved.